# In html how to remove onmouseover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

can anyone let me know how to remove (onmouseover="mouseoversound.playclip()") in the below html

```
<a href="roster.html" onmouseover="mouseoversound.playclip()">Roster</a>
```

Instead of this can we use in js file i.e. #nav li a hover event play clip. Below is the reference link:
javascriptkit.com/script/script2/soundlink.shtml

Answer (score 4):

I think that the responders didn't **fully** read your question. Since the event is bound inline (which someone mentioned IS deprecated) we can just remove the onmouseover attribute within the anchor.

In the example below, I've just attached an onclick inline event. Clicking the link will remove the event bind.

You can do with in straight JavaScript:

```
<a href="roster.html" onmouseover="mouseoversound.playclip()" onclick="this.removeAttribute('onmouseover')">Roster</a>
```

Without using an inline onclick on that element, you could just use this:

```
<a id="Link1" href="roster.html" onmouseover="mouseoversound.playclip()">Roster</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('Link1').removeAttribute('onmouseover')">Remove onmouseover</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

First usage of inline code inside the Markup-HTML is **deprecated** as it break the concept of *"separate of concerns"*

---

You can give it an id:

```
<a id="foo" href="roster.html" onmouseover="mouseoversound.playclip()">Roster</a>
```

Then override it:

```
document.getElementById('foo').onmouseover = null;
```

If you want to override all the `onmouseover` of links in your page:

```
$('a').each(function(){
                 this.onmouseover = null;
            });
```

Comment: The nav items links built via cms so i would like to remove this (onmouseover="mouseoversound.playclip()") in anchor elements...

Comment: @DesigningStudios. Updated, though I can't really understand your situation!

Comment: @gdoron: He tried to tell you that he'd like to avoid having inline event handlers in HTML but those navigation elements are built by CMS he can't control. So these handlers stay in HTML. You answer on the other hand is relevant and helpful. +1 for that.

Answer (score 2):

```
function  mouseoversound.playclip(){
/*      your code        */

//add this

this.onmouseover = null;
```

}

you can do like than

#### or like that

```
function  mouseoversound.playclip(isRemove){
/*      your code        */

  //add this

  if(isRemove)  this.onmouseover = null;
}

<a href="roster.html" onmouseover="mouseoversound.playclip(true)">Roster</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery and want to remove it completely from html

```
 $("#nav a").removeAttr('onmouseover')
```